# JWPlayer play command issue on safari

Tags: video, safari, jwplayer

JWPlayer's `play()` command / script doesn't seem to work on Safari at initial state. Does anyone have this issue?

For example, I'll take the following as my sample:

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/demos/advanced/set-playback-rate/

On Safari browser console, when I execute `jwplayer().play()`, the video doesn't run.

If I start the video by clicking the display/control, and then pause, and then run `jwplayer().play()` again, it works fine.

So, this seems to only happen at the very beginning. And it only happens on Safari.

Chrome and Firefox are working fine. I'm using jwplayer v8.

Does anyone have any clue how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is due to the autoplay policy, and requires user gesture:

https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/issues/2421#issuecomment-333130812